# Uncaught Invariant Violation : Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This can happen when a component repeatedly calls `setState` inside `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate`. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I cannot route to the `authenticationRoute` destination because of this error.

**Console Output:**

> index.js:1446 The above error occurred in the  component:
>
> ```
> in Redirect (at Auth.jsx:101)
> in div (at Auth.jsx:116)
> in Auth (created by Context.Consumer)
> in Connect(Auth) (created by Route)
> in Route (at App.js:27)
> in Switch (at App.js:26)
> in div (at App.js:46)
> in App (created by Context.Consumer)
> in Connect(App) (created by Route)
> in Route (created by withRouter(Connect(App)))
> in withRouter(Connect(App)) (at src/index.js:28)
> in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
> in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:27)
> in Provider (at src/index.js:26)
> ```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Input from '../../components/Input/input';
import Button from '../../components/Button/button';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as service from '../../services/AuthService';

 class Auth extends Component {
     state = {
        controls: {
            username: {
               //..
            },
            password: {
               //..
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false
            }
        }
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        if ( this.props.isAuthenticated && this.props.authRedirectPath !== '/' ) {
            this.props.onSetAuthRedirectPath('/home');
        }
    }


    handleSubmit=(event)=> {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.auth(this.state.controls.username.value,this.state.controls.password.value)
       
    }
    render() {

        let errorMessage = null;
        let button= button=<Button btnType="Success">Login</Button>
        let authRedirect = null;
        if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
            **authRedirect = <Redirect to={this.props.authRedirectPath}/>** //line 101
        }
        return (
        <div>
            {authRedirect}
                        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                           {form}
                        {button}
                        </form>
              
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )( Auth );
```

Comment: Dude, are you sure `this.props.authRedirectPath` is not undefined ?

Comment: Yeah, in redux reducer `const intialState`

Comment: okay well sometimes the issue fallback to the component which you rendering Auth.js in, show us App.js

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to include where you are updating state in componentDidUpdate or componentWillUpdate, but why not build up an object with all of your state updates and then just make one call to setState?

Comment: `class App extends Component {
  render() {
    if ( this.state.isAuthenticated ) {
      routes = (
        <Layout>
            <Switch>
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Redirect to="/auth" />
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
        
      );
    }
  
    return (
        <div className='App'>
        {routes}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated
  };
};`

Comment: yikes, couldnt you format that better ?

Comment: @MikeFeltman yeah, im using redux store to manage most of my states. since isAuthenticated is used in this component. i initialized it there and use MapStatetoProps

Comment: sorry @superrcoop , i couldnt do better :/

Comment: Both componentWillUpdate and componentWillMount are deprecated. You might want to completely refactor this to not make use of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How are you checking for authentication ?

Its best you initialize isAuthenticated in the redux-store so you can use it globally in your components before its rendered

So, instead of

`if (this.state.isAuthenticated) {routes=<div>..</div>}`

Try

`if (this.props.isAuthenticated{routes=<div>..</div>}`

Instance Properties

props

> this.props contains the props that were defined by the caller of
>   this component. See Components and Props for an introduction to props.

state

> this.state contains data specific to this component that may
>   change over time. The state is user-defined, and it should be a plain
>   JavaScript object.

See State and Lifecycle for more information about the state.
[React.Component Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#props)

Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

Also, ensure mapStateToProps is pointing to your reducer

`return {isAuthenticated : state.`{reducer}`.isAuthenticated}`