# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set state after a function has finished and I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

I'm calling setstate in a callback after the function has finished so I thought this would work ok from what I've read, but I can't seem to make it work.

Running the function addStuff when component updates

```
componentDidUpdate() {
   this.addStuff(() => this.setState({"loading":false}))
}
```

Setting a callback when complete

```
addStuff(callback) {
    ...Does a bunch of stuff
    callback();
}
```

Can anyone suggest what I may be doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: No it's true by default in app state

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Invariant Violation : Maximum update depth exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790781/uncaught-invariant-violation-maximum-update-depth-exceeded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the infinite loop is that you did not wrap your `setState` in a **condition**, but in a callback.

So what I think happens is that as soon as your component updates, `setState` is called, which triggers a re-render, which means that `componentDidUpdate` is called, which sets state, which triggers a re-render, which calls `componentDidUpdate` , etc.

This is the reason why setting state in `componentDidUpdate` should always be **conditional**, as specified in [the example in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). In your case, maybe it could look like this, where you compare relevant props to verify that you indeed need to rerender :

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.relevantProp!== prevProps.relevantProp) {
    this.addStuff(() => this.setState({"loading":false}))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you read the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate), it clears states "You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop." So with your function it is the same thing that is happening.